# Automatically restart the daemons in chef cookbooks when new recipes are applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, chef-infra, restart, chef-recipe

I am a beginner for chef. I have a project hosted in Engineyard with chef cookbooks. Now the requirement is to automatically restart the particular daemon when a new recipe is uploaded and applied to the daemon.

How do I get information on when the recipes are applied? Is version in cookbooks will help me anyway?

Using deploy hooks is a good option? If so how can I implement the condition that the particular file has been updated and implement a restart only if it has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Any resource that is relevant to the service (usually one or more `template` resources for configuration, possibly a `package` resource) will be set up to send a notification to restart the `service` resource corresponding to the daemon. This usually looks something like this:

```
package 'thingy' do
  notifies :restart, 'service[thingy]'
end

template '/etc/thingy.conf' do
  source 'thingy.conf.erb'
  notifies :restart, 'service[thingy]'
end

service 'thingy' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

Comment: what about using deploy hooks?

Comment: Those are not a thing you should use, assuming you mean the stuff from the `deploy` resource.